# UK standard visitor visa, mistake in previous name

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

I am planning to visit London with my wife and son. I already have a valid UK visitor visa. I have filled the application for my wife and son and soon after making the payment, I realized that there was a question saying, were you known by any other names prior to this name?

I selected NO for this question while making the application for my wife. However, My wife's official last name was different before our marriage and it got changed after marriage. Now I have following questions:

1. Can this become a reason for refusal?
2. My appointment is not yet done. I have the option to cancel the application and get the full refund. If I do this, can I make another application from scratch for the same person?

The only problem in option 2 is that my wife's application number GWF is mentioned in my son's application, which means I have to cancel both of them. Any help on this is highly appreciated and can save my time and money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one can predict the outcome, but best practices would indicate that an absolutely fresh application should be made. This is to avoid two important considerations:

- a credibility hit on the application if it is discovered; and
- having to perpetuate the lie in future applications so as to be consistent.

Previous names are an important data item, and clicking "yes" opens up a sub-menu. Accordingly, a simple pen and ink correction  to say "yes" will not suffice.

Yes, again best practice; cancel the application and say it had a mistake, not a big deal.

And you do not need to cancel your son's application. You can change the GWF in the remarks section with a simple pen and ink correction.

Best practices prevail when there are no explicit rules, and generally reflect what you could expect to hear from an experienced lawyer.

Comment: is the pen edit allowed at all? will this not cause an issue in my son's application?

Comment: Yes it is allowed and you can mention that to the staff taking your application when you go for your bio-metrics. Better yet you can make the change in front of them so they can make a note